# Дублированный возврат функции через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет! У меня проблема возникла, уже часа три вожусь с ней, все бестолку. Имеется такой jQuery:

```
 function refresh_day_actions() {
        $("#add_postavshik_1").bind('click', function(){
            var i = 0;
            $('[prih_id]').each(function(){
                i++;
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxcore.php",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                data: "action=add_postavshik_1&counter=" + i,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#postavshik_results_1").append(response);
                        add_postavshik_1_actions();
                    }
            });

        });

    }

    function add_postavshik_1_actions(){

        $('[id^="prih_add"]').bind('click', function(){
            var prih_addID = $(this).attr("id").slice(8);
            console.log(prih_addID);            
        });

    }
```

Из `ajaxcore.php` возвращается верстка, кнопка с `id = "prih_add"` + какое-то число. При нажатии на нее в консоль вывожу `prih_addID`. При повторном возврате верстки (при повторном нажатии `"#add_postavshik_1"`) я вновь вызываю функцию `add_postavshik_1_actions();`, которая содержит обработчик нажатия кнопки `"#prih_add"`. У нас получается две кнопки `"prih_add"` в диве `"postavshik_results_1"`. Проблема в том, что при нажатии каждой последнесозданной кнопки `prih_add`, `console.log(prih_addID)` выполняется числу, равное числу созданных кнопок `prih_add`. Вот такая вот ерунда. Есть ли какой-нибудь `break;`, который можно было бы использовать вне цикла?

Пытался еще вот так:

```
function add_postavshik_1_actions(event) {
    $('[id^="prih_add"]').bind('click', function(){
        var prih_addID = $(this).attr("id").slice(8);
        console.log(prih_addID);            
    });            
    $(this).off(event);
}
```

В таком случае получаю эффект прямо противоположный. Подскажите кто-нибудь, как сделать так, чтобы каждая созданная кнопка "нажималась" один раз при таких обстоятельствах (при подгрузке верстки аяксом), т.е. `console.log(prih_addID);` выполнялся один раз.

Заранее спасибо! Если плохо написал, плохо объяснил суть проблемы, я постараюсь подробнее написать, просто у самого уже крыша едет со всем этим делом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй `<a href="http://api.jquery.com/on/">.on()</a>`

JavaScript

```
$('container').on('click', 'selector', function(){
})
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/9epgtuc0/